# Elasticsearch query on fields with mulitple values, one match scored equal

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index that is storing some fields as arrays as they could have multiple values, like first/last names as we keep historical data on maiden name, nickname ect

```
     {
        "_index": "structured",
        "_type": "entity",
        "_id": "0000230799",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "FIRST_NAME": [
              "Deborah",
              "Debbie"
           ],

           "LAST_NAME": [
              "Loverde",
              "Frogameni"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "structured",
        "_type": "entity",
        "_id": "0000309483",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "FIRST_NAME": [
              "Anthony",
              "Tony"
           ],
           "LAST_NAME": "Frogameni",
     },
```

however, when i do a search where a doc has more than one value on the property, it will give a lower score than a doc that only had one value on the property that matched

using the index above, it scores the second record higher,  due to the first record having two last names versus the second record's one

how can i say if i match one value on a field with multiple values, it is scored the same 
as a field with only one value? like max i need matched here is 1

```
   POST /structured/entity/_search?explain=true
    {
     "query": { 
        "bool":{
            "should":[
            { 

                   "match_phrase_prefix":{
                    "FIRST_NAME":{"query":"debbi"}
                    }

            },
            { 

                   "match_phrase_prefix":{
                    "LAST_NAME":"frogameni"
                    }

            }  

     ]
        }

    }
}
```

any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider switching to the [BM25-similarity model](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#bm25). Specifically, you want to set the `b`-value to `0`.

Also, here's a more in depth comparison of Elasticsearch/Lucene's default similarity model and BM25: [Similarity in Elasticsearch](https://www.found.no/foundation/similarity/).

Comment: for anyone else looking, put index.similarity.default.type: BM25 in your elasticsearch.yml file. Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the minimum should match setting in the wrong place. You also need to set it to 2 rather than 1 so you have to match both terms. Try this instead

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "FIRST_NAME": {
              "query": "debbi"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "LAST_NAME": "frogameni"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  },
  "from": "0",
  "size": "11"
}
```

Comment: Ok, i get that, but if i added a third criteria, i would always have to bump up my minimum should match, my question should have been how can I say a match on a field with two values is scored the same as a match on the same field that only has one value